# Need Expert Advice for using sklearn pipeline to create a composite estimator with multiple models & features

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use sklearn pipeline to create a composite estimator. Please check attached image for model blueprint. Can anyone help me understand how this can be done in python.

Column Transformer with Mixed Types

Dataset has only 3 columns including target. [featur_1: categorical, feature_2: text, target]

[image: Model Blueprint]

Code (that didn't work!!)

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline




# Split the data into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['description'], df['reject'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Separate transformers for text and categorical data
text_transformer = TfidfVectorizer()
categorical_transformer = OrdinalEncoder()

# Create a FeatureUnion for combining the outputs of different transformers
combined_features = FeatureUnion([
    ('text', text_transformer, 'description'),
    ('categorical', categorical_transformer, [['reject']])
])

# Create an instance of the SGDClassifier
sgd_classifier = SGDClassifier()

# Create a pipeline for the model
model_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', combined_features),
    ('sgd', sgd_classifier),  # Stochastic Gradient Descent Classifier
    ('lgbm', LGBMClassifier())  # LightGBM Classifier
])

# Fit the pipeline on the training data
model_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict on the test data
predictions = model_pipeline.predict(X_test)

# Evaluate the accuracy
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy}')
```

- 

```
Error:
"name": "TypeError",
"message": "All intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'SGDClassifier()' (type <class 'sklearn.linear_model._stochastic_gradient.SGDClassifier'>) doesn't",
```

- 